# Using the result of a query in another query without subquerying

Tags: oracle

I have a query that creates a result with two columns of ints.

```
from_id | to_id
---------------
  51    |  100
  3     |  21
  ...   |  ...
```

Let's call this result `map_ids`

Then, can I do something like

```
SELECT * FROM some_table st WHERE st.id IN map_ids.to_id
```

to only select stuff from `some_table` that has an ID that matches the result of the `to_id` in the first query?

I want to avoid using a subquery because the query that generate `map_ids` is quite long and is actually used twice in the real select from `some_table`.

Comment: Are you looking for [subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2077142)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2077142). You can put your first query into a `with` clause and then join to that in the main body:

```
WITH map_ids (from_id, to_id) as (
   ... you first query ...
)
SELECT columns
FROM map_ids mi
JOIN some_table st ON st.id = mi.to_id
```

You can refer to `map_ids` again later, e.g. in another branch of a `union`.

You can do something like `where st.id in (select to_id from map_ids)` but joining is probably clearer (and maybe more efficient, depending on what the optimiser does with the real query).